# Power absorbed by a resistor in a crossed circuit

Tags: power, passive-networks, steady-state

[image]

The given problem above is asking for the power absorbed by the resistor R given R = 1 Ohm. According to my professor, the two inductors do not cross so I redrew the circuit into the one shown in the image below. I then redrew the circuit into its phasor equivalent also shown in the same photo.

[image]

I then did the following steps:

```
KVL at I1:

-2 + I1(2j-j/2) - I2(2j) – I3(-j/2) = 0

(3/2)j I1 - 2j I2 + j/2 I3 = 2  (1)

KVL at I2:

I2(2j+1+-j/2) – I1(2j) – I3(1) = 0

-2jI1 + (1+(3/2)j)I2 – I3 = 0     (2)


KVL at I3:

I3(1+2j – j/2) – I1(-j/2) – I2(1) = 0

j/2 I1 – I2 + (1+(3/2)j I3) = 0  (3)


Using Cramer’s Rule to get I2 and I3:


Divisor:

[((3/2)j)(1+(3/2)j)(1+(3/2)j) + (-2j)(1)(j/2) + (j/2)(-2j)(-1)] - 

[(j/2)(1+(3/2)j)(j/2) + (-1)(-1)((3/2)j) + (1+(3/2)j)(-2j)(-2j)]

= -1/4 + 3j

Dividend for I2:

[0 + 2(-1)(j/2)+0] – [0+0+(1+(3/2)j)(-2j)(2)] = -6+3j

Dividend for I3:

[0+0+(2)(-2j)(-1)] – [(j/2)(1+(3/2)j)(2)] = 3/2 + 3j


I2 = (-6+3j )/ (-1/4 + 3j) = 168/145 +(276/145)j

I3 = (3/2 +3j) / (-1/4 + 3j) = 138/145 – (84/145) j


I2 + I3 =   [168/145 +(276/145)j] + [138/145 – (84/145) j] = 306/145 + (192/145)j

Using the Average power equation:

P(1-Ohm) =(1/2)|306/145 + (192/145)j|^2 Re{1} = 3.1 W
```

The answer in the book however is 2 W. Where did I go wrong? Is my redrawn circuit correct? Thanks.

Thoughts on using the Thevenin equivalent circuit to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The inductors are crossed.

The circuit is also symmetrical - such that the voltage across the top capacitor is opposite to the voltage of the bottom capacitor.  Similar rule applies to inductor current.  Let's exploit the symmetry.

Result:  the rms dissipated power in the resistor is indeed 2 W.

**KCL:**

\$ i_3=i_1+i_2  \$

**KVL1:** (around the voltage source, the two capacitors, and the resistor)

\$ V=2Z_1i_1+i_3R = 2Z_1i_1+Ri_1+Ri_2  \$

**KVL2:** (around the voltage source, L2, and C2)

\$ V=-Z_2i_2+i_1Z_1  \$

Solution:

\$ R=1\Omega, V = 2V, Z1 = 1/(\omega Cj) = -0.5j, Z2 = \omega Lj = 2j\$

\$ i_1= (V+VR/Z_2)/(2Z_1+R+RZ_1/Z_2)\$

\$ i_2= (i_1Z_1-V)/Z_2\$

\$ i_1= 1.6+0.8j\$

\$ i_2= -0.4+0.8j\$

\$ i_3= 1.2+1.6j\$

Absolute value of the resistor current phasor is 2 A.  The rms is then \$ \sqrt 2A \$ and the power dissipation \$ P = Ri_3^2=1\Omega*(\sqrt2A)^2=2W\$

Notice that due to the capacitor/resistor value symmetry the dissipated power is independent of the excitation frequency.

Schematic (Z1 are the capacitors, Z2 are the inductors):

[image]

Results:

[image]

> Thoughts on using the Thevenin equivalent circuit to solve this problem?

Not sure what Thevenin will give you here- the circuit can be solved using two KVLs! Also, the impedances are frequency dependent and Thevenin/Norton theorems are typically used for DC voltage/current sources and resistive networks.

Btw. thank you for this interesting question!  I had fun solving it :).

Comment: Hmm suppose the inductors are not crossed, is my answer correct? Or is there something wrong with the redrawn circuit? Thanks! I'll try solving the problem using your approach with your redrawn circuit. Also, what do you think of using Thevenin transform to solve this problem?

Comment: It looks that the circuit is redrawn correctly.  It does look like the same circuit as mine.  Not sure what Thevenin will give you here- the circuit can be solved using two KVLs!  Also, the impedances are frequency dependent and Thevenin/Norton theorems are typically used for DC voltage/current sources and resistive networks.

Comment: If our circuits are similar, why did I not get the same answer? Also, I can't really understand your KVL equations as I can't clearly picture out which meshes they are referring to.  I'm really sorry if my questions are rather ignorant, I'm still in the process of learning electric circuit analysis. Thanks for your input.

Comment: There was a small mistake in the second KVL (factor of 2).  I have also added an explanation of how the KVL equations are formed.  Good luck learning :)